# Use environment variables with SVN checkout in Hudson?

Tags: svn, hudson, environment-variables

We're running Hudson 1.368 with SVN 1.17 on Windows. My goal is to set an environment variable (under Manage Hudson) that I can use in my SVN checkout directory.  I tried this:

```
http://svn/repos/name/${EnvironmentVariable}
```

But I received the following error.

```
Location 'http://svn/repos/name/${EnvironmentVariable}' does not exist
```

That is, the variable wasn't expanded.

What's the trick?

Comment: Have you tried not using the curly braces (i.e. $EnvironmentVariable)? Have you tried surrounding the variable name with %?

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had to use the [setenv plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Setenv+Plugin). You might want to check that out.

Comment: This could work, but I do recall not requiring a plugin in order to use environment variables in my jobs.